# Problem setting dynamic hash name using Eval in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dynamic

I have this line of code to set a hash key to an xy coordinate pair and set its value to a class instance:

```
gates[eval("gate#{inputx}_#{inputy}")] = Gate.new(in1, in2)
```

However, I get an undefined variable error when I run. If I set inputx and inputy to 3 and 4 respectively, I get this:

```
undefined local variable or method `gate3_4' for main:Object (NameError)
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `eval` here is superflous, what you probably want is string substitution:

`gates["gate#{inputx}_#{inputy}"] = Gate.new(in1, in2)`

Using `eval("gate#{inputx}_#{inputy}")` first substitutes the string, then performs the `eval` on said string: `eval("gate3_4")`, which is why it complains that the variable is missing, because you are executing this ruby sentence `gate3_4`.